# Table cell reorder + iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to reorder my rows of table.in my table cell data is filled by nsmutablearray. When i am reordering my cells at that time i want to reorder my array data as  i am reordering cell.
I  am beginner .I cant do this.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort the array the way you want and the call `reloadData`

Comment: just create a new project with Master detail template.. in viewDidLoad of MasterViewController, edit button will be commented, just uncomment it and run the app.. this is the best sample...

Answer (score 0):

Just dig into Apples own documentation regarding reordering of table rows! In particular refer to the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) and read through the "Managing the Reordering of Rows" section of the beforementioned guide.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated, this is all described in the Table View Programming Guide for iOS. Specifically, you want to move an element in your array to match the moved table row. This is done in the table view data source method **tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:**